# wget proxy authentication error

Tags: solaris, wget

I get the following error when trying to connect to a http URL through a proxy using wget

the error:

```
  wget "http://pro.fastmarkets.com/feeds/default.aspx?usr=anzbank&pwd=587345bv98735vb2b56&feed=physicals-csv" -O /tmp/test.csv
**wget: Error in /home/acdbaqa/.wgetrc at line 3.**
--06:04:15--  http://pro.fastmarkets.com/feeds/default.aspx?usr=anzbank&pwd=587345bv98735vb2b56&feed=physicals-csv
           => `/tmp/test.csv'

Connecting to 59.154.134.109:80... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 407 Proxy Authentication Required
06:04:15 ERROR 407: Proxy Authentication Required.
```

my .wgetrc file contents:

```
http_proxy=59.154.134.109:80
proxy_user=ACPROXYPROD
proxy_password=test
#password='Ev*luti*n0456789'
#proxy-password='Ev*luti*n0456789'
ftp_proxy=204.2.23.10:80
```

line 3 is the password. am i missing anything here? not sure why it says error at line 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Τhis was solved by changing the `.wgetrc` file with the below parameters

```
proxy-user=ACPROXYPROD
proxy-passwd=test1245
```

it is **NOT** `proxy_user` and `proxy_password`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an older `wget` release where the password setting used the following syntax (note the missing "**or**" in passw<s>or</s>d):

```
proxy_passwd=test
```