# centos6.8 wget error: Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: proxy, wget, centos6

I got following error message when I tried to connect to web site through proxy with `wget` on centos 6.8.

**ERROR**

```
wget http://www.yahoo.co.jp
--2016-12-16 14:47:04 http://www.yahoo.co.jp
Connecting to 172.30.10.124:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 407 Proxy Authentication Required
2016-12-16 14:47:04 ERROR 407: Proxy Authentication Required
```

**CHECKED**

I confirm this command is running.

```
export http_proxy='http://guest:gstPass@172.30.10.124:8080'
wget http://www.yahoo.co.jp
```

**~/.wgetrc**

This is contents of ~/.wgetrc

```
http_proxy = 172.30.10.124:8080
https_proxy = 172.30.10.124:8080
ftp_proxy = 172.30.10.124:8080
proxy_user = "guest"
proxy_passwd = "gstPass"
(I do not edit /etc/wgetrc)
```

**wget version**

This is version of `wget`

```
GNU Wget 1.12 built on linux-gnu
```

I also read [wget proxy authentication error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096703/wget-proxy-authentication-error) but no change.

Where should I check? Where are the mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this problem. I changed value of `proxy_user` and `proxy_passwd`.

**BEFORE**

```
http_proxy = 172.30.10.124:8080
https_proxy = 172.30.10.124:8080
ftp_proxy = 172.30.10.124:8080
proxy_user = "guest"
proxy_passwd = "gstPass"
```

**AFTER**

```
http_proxy = 172.30.10.124:8080
https_proxy = 172.30.10.124:8080
ftp_proxy = 172.30.10.124:8080
proxy_user = guest
proxy_passwd = gstPass
```

I need not ' " ' for `proxy_user` and `proxy_passwd`